# How to move to next insert point with emmet in PHP Storm?

Tags: phpstorm, emmet

I am using the default implementation of emmet in PHP Storm.

When I type:

```
div+p+bq
```

and press `TAB` I get the following code and can begin typing inside the `div` element:

[image]

But how can I then easily jump from there inside the `p` element, and then inside the `blockquote`element instead of having to navigate to them with the arrow keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When finished typing your `skdfjsdf` just **press Enter** to get to another place holder.

**P.S.**
If you will use any other Emmet action / live template / etc (that introduces new place holders) while in place holder, all other place holders will be cancelled.